# RequestsDependencyWarning: when running gsutil command

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, gcloud, gsutil

Im gettng the below error when i try to run this command on ubuntu 18
`gsutil ls`

/snap/google-cloud-sdk/161/lib/third_party/requests/**init**.py:83: RequestsDependencyWarning: Old version of cryptography ([1, 2, 3]) may cause slowdown.

Tried to run `gcloud components update` but i got this error

(gcloud.components.update) You cannot perform this action because this Cloud SDK installation is managed by an external package manager.
Please consider using a separate installation of the Cloud SDK created through the default mechanism described at: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/

Am i missing anything ?

Answer (score 1):

This is because your python interpreter and his dependencies are outdated, also, your Gcloud SDK package was installed via snap package, when Gcloud SDK is installed via apt repository or snap package the command `gcloud components update` will not work, instead you need to run the proper command to update your packages, in your case you need to run this command to update your snap packages

```
sudo snap refresh
```

To update the python's packages `cryptography` and `request` you need to install the OS package `python-pip` and after that update your outdated packages

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
python -m pip install --upgrade cryptography
python -m pip install --upgrade requests
```

Since this is a warning message, you can continue working with gcloud/gsutil, but keeping your Python interpreter updated will allow you to use new functions in software written in Python, for example, the Gcloud SDK.

Comment: Im getting below error wheni try running above commands 
N: Ignoring file 'google-cloud-sdk.list.bkp' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/ cloud-sdk: /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg !=
E: The list of sources could not be read.
N: Ignoring file 'google-cloud-sdk.list.bkp' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an

Comment: invalid filename extension
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/ cloud-sdk: /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg !=
E: The list of sources could not be read.

Comment: This looks like a corruption on the package manager try to remove your snap package and re install the sdk by following the [recommended install steps for ubuntu](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install#installation_instructions)